# Google Account Sign in atempt prevented! Cannot sign in to play store

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, samsung-galaxy-y-duos

I cannot sign in to a Google Account for enabling Play Store in my Device(Galaxy Y duos GT S6102). When I try to add a Google account, it says that my Username & Password don't match. Then when I opened my gmail from my PC, I found a mail from google which said "Sign in attempt Prevented from an app that does'nt meet modern security standards". Once by mistake I uninstalled Play Store & now I have reinstalled it. Is this the reason for not meeting modern security standards? What can I do to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try heading to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and seeing if you can turn on access to the application.

Comment: That worked. But still I am looking for better solutions, that is, how to make my phone meet modern security standards.